# Replacing all items in a multidimensional array with random values

Tags: c#, arrays

for a single dimensional array normally I would use a for loop like the one below but I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve lots of loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
{
    myArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 500);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how many dimensions the array has?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359881/how-to-set-values-in-a-multidimensional-array-using-a-linear-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try *low level* [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.90).aspx) to conceal the loop(s):

```
  // N-D array (whatever dimensions)
  int[,,] array = new int[3, 5, 11]; 

  Buffer.BlockCopy(
    Enumerable
      .Range(0, array.Length)
      .Select(x => rand.Next(0, 500))
      .ToArray(),
    0,
    array,
    0,
    array.Length * sizeof(int)); // sizeof(int) : we copy bytes...
```

we create 1-D array

```
    Enumerable
      .Range(0, array.Length)
      .Select(x => rand.Next(0, 500))
      .ToArray()
```

with the total length of N-D one (`array.Length == array.Length(0) * ... * array.GetLEngth(N)`) and copy it into N-D one.

Comment: This won't work because it copies the result of the `Enumerable` and doesn't manipulate the source array. You basically manipulate a temporary array and do nothing with it.

Comment: @Tamir Vered: Thank you! You're quite right: I put the routine prematurely: wrong argument order (source and target swapped) and wrong *bytes* size (should have been multiplied by `sizeof(int)`)

Answer (score 0):

Use more than one loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; ++j)
    {
        myArray[i][j] = rand.Next(0, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: ++i vs i++ shouldn't be?

Comment: He says "I can't think of a way to do this that doesn't involve lots of loops.".

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak In this usage it doesn't matter because the return value of the increment is not being used.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-i-and-i-in-a-loop

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I got into the habit of using `++i` instead of `i++` after learning C++ where you should use `++it` on iterators.

Comment: That's not a multidimensional but a jagged array (although the global principle still hold)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Actually it makes the question quite different since the memory is allocated inconsecutively so it isn't possible to use `Buffer.BlockCopy` for example, nor other "look on this array as a single dimension block of memory" solutions.

Comment: @TamirVered I was talking about the principle of that answer not the question